# How to apply Newton's method to solve for a root of a function that is not everywhere defined?

Tags: nonlinear-system, constraints, newton-raphson

If I want to solve for a root of a nonlinear function $f$, I would naturally consider using Newton's method, starting from an initial guess $x_0$:

$$
x_{k+1} = x_{k} - \frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}
$$

Now, if $f$ is not defined everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$, what can I do to make this work?

Examples: $f(x)=\sqrt{x}-1$ and $f(x) = \ln{x}$ are not defined for $x<0$ (both have a root at $x=1$)

During iteration, the Newton's method iterations could accidentally end up at a point $x_{k+1} < 0$. How to proceed from there?

## Questions

1. Can Newton's method be adapted to take care of these situations, and how?
2. What alternative approaches are there?

Approaches that also work for the multi-dimensional case are encouraged.

Comment: Sometimes, it is only a matter of finding a suitable starting value. But the method can also fail for every start value (except of course a root). Your examples however should work. Other methods are the bisection method and regula falsi.

Comment: Very nice is the fix-point-method, but it is somewhat limited.

Comment: @Peter: you say "Your examples however should work." But for $f(x)=\sqrt{x}-1$ and $x_0=5$, $x_1=2\sqrt{5}-5=-0.5278.. < 0$, and you can't evaluate $f(x)$ anymore. How can it still work?

Comment: I admit, I did not check it. Did you try other stariting values ? $1.5$ for example works. $3$ works as well. As said, the method need not work for all start values (in the worst case only for roots as a start value).

Comment: @Peter The square root problem is not the actual problem I'm facing. I have a multi-dimensional problem where one of the equations is not defined in some region of the domain. I've simplified the problem to focus on its essential properties. In my actual problem, it is tough to find a suitable starting point.

Comment: In fact that can be a real challenge! I would suggest to calculate points on a relatively tight grid to find a suitable start value. I don't think that there is a method doing the job in every possible case.

Comment: When you code it up, you could simply coerce values to be in the domain of the function as you go. But then you might not have convergence, unless you're able to introduce some randomness to the algorithm (in the right direction so that the new value is still in the domain).

Comment: Something that might help you is using a heigher order of newtons method, eg: Newton Raphson. There will always be initial points where your $x_n$ is out of your region. Improving your initial guess will help.